# Spark 1.5.2: Filtering a dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` with the following columns:

```
ts: Timestamp
val: String
```

From my master df, I want to select dataframes that only match a certain `ts` value. I can achieve that using `between` like: 
`df.filter($"ts".between(targetDate, targetDate))` Here `targetDate` is the date I want to filter my df on. Is there an equivalent `equal` such as `df.filter($"ts".equal(targetDate))` ?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [Column's documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column), you can use the `===` method to compare column's values with `Any` type of variable.

[image: === Method]

```scala
val df = sc.parallelize(
  ("2016-02-24T22:54:17Z", "foo") :: 
  ("2010-08-01T00:00:12Z", "bar") ::
  Nil
).toDF("ts", "val").withColumn("ts", $"ts".cast("timestamp"))

df.where($"ts" === "2010-08-01T00:00:12Z").show(10, false)
// +---------------------+---+
// |ts                   |val|
// +---------------------+---+
// |2010-08-01 02:00:12.0|bar|
// +---------------------+---+
```

If you want to be explicit about types you can replace

```
 === "2010-08-01T00:00:12Z"
```

with

```
=== lit("2010-08-01T00:00:12Z").cast("timestamp")
```

There is also `Column.equalTo` method designed for Java interoperability:

```
 df.where($"ts".equalTo("2010-08-01T00:00:12Z")).show(10, false)
```

Finally Spark supports `NULL` safe equality operators (`<=>`, `Column.eqNullSafe`) but these require Cartesian product in Spark < 1.6 (see [SPARK-11111](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11111)).

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto AFAIK there isn't. You can link Java docs. Also, could rollback to the previous version which includes null safe information and edit on top of that?

Comment: I don't say you do :) When you check history ([click on edited ...](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35640010/revisions)) and go to specific edit there is a rollback link. You'll even get a badge for that ;)

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Thanks!

Comment: @Neel Could you either accept the answer or explain why it doesn't work for you so it can be improved? Thanks !